# How to get chats from Microsoft teams in my web app?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I want to create Agile Meeting Dashboard web app, where chats of Microsoft teams is taken as action items for team members. I want to take chats from my Microsoft team's channel to my web app using API.

please explain how to get Bearer token for get request for chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this using an Outgoing Webhook. See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook).